# XSLT Transform to XML

Tags: xslt

I have some xml in the following format:

```
  <top>
        <topValue Value="1#1#5" />
        <topValue Value="2#2#10" />
        <topValue Value="1#1#3" />
        <topValue Value="2#2#30" /> 
   </top>
```

and output should look like that:

```
  <boo>
       <booEnrty>
            <v>5</v>
            <v>10</v>
        </booEnrty>

        <booEnrty>
            <v>3</v>
            <v>30</v>
        </booEnrty>
     </boo>
```

my XSLT to transform

```
<boo>
        <xsl:for-each select="top/topValue">        
            <xsl:if test="position() mod 2 = 0">
                <booEnrty> 
                    <v><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-after(@Value,'#'),'#')"/></v>                   
                </booEnrty> 
          </xsl:if>
     </xsl:for-each> 
    </boo>
```

What should the XSLT document look like to do this transform?
Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: It should look very good;). What have you tried?

Comment: i have with <xsl:if test="position() mod 2 = 0"> tired. but it did not work :(

Comment: Can you show the XSLT in your question, I am sure someone will help. Could you also provide more information on rules how <booEntry><v> should be created. XSLT1 or XSLT2?

Comment: ok. thanks:)i use XSLT1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe someone got a better approach to this, but the XSLT below works for your case.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="top">
    <boo>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="topValue[position() mod 2 = 1]"/>
    </boo>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="topValue[position() mod 2 = 1]">
    <booEntry>
        <v>
            <xsl:call-template name="substring-after-last">
                <xsl:with-param name="string" select="@Value" />
                <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="'#'" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </v>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]"/>
    </booEntry>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="topValue">
    <v>
        <xsl:call-template name="substring-after-last">
            <xsl:with-param name="string" select="@Value" />
            <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="'#'" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </v>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="substring-after-last">
    <xsl:param name="string" />
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($string, $delimiter)">
            <xsl:call-template name="substring-after-last">
                <xsl:with-param name="string"
                    select="substring-after($string, $delimiter)" />
                <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="$delimiter" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="$string"/></xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @eriv if you are happy with the answer then please mark it as the answer ;-)

Comment: ok:) Any idea how to solve that using array?Is there anyway to create a multi dimensional array in xsl? ( 1#1#5---> x=1, y=1 dann return 5)

Answer (score 0):

How about something short and simple?

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/top">
    <boo>
        <xsl:for-each select="topValue[position() mod 2 = 1]">        
            <booEnrty> 
                <xsl:for-each select=". | following-sibling::topValue[1]">
                    <v>
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-after(@Value,'#'),'#')"/>
                    </v> 
                </xsl:for-each> 
            </booEnrty>
        </xsl:for-each> 
    </boo>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```